# Problem with pst-barcode when using \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, barcodes, pst-barcode

I've tried to use the pst-barcode to generate QR codes, and ran into an issue with foreign characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)
  \psbarcode{ÆØÅæøå}{width=1.0 height=1.0}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
ÆØÅæøå
\end{document}
```

[image: Incorrect (and complex) QR code]
*Incorrect (and complex) QR code*

This does not give the expected (or wanted) result. Removing the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` solves the pst-barcode problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)
  \psbarcode{ÆØÅæøå}{width=1.0 height=1.0}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
ÆØÅæøå
\end{document}
```

[image: Correct QR code, but wrong encoding for text in LaTeX]
*Correct QR code, but wrong encoding for text in LaTeX*

However, this breaks the input encoding of LaTeX...
I presume that pst-barcode does not support UTF8.

What would be the best way to get both UTF-8 encoded LaTeX and correct QR codes for foreign characters?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post. You can include the images but remove the `!` before them, then one with enough reputation can append it for them to appear inline.

Comment: Thanks @N.N., understood - I now added the QR Code images.

Answer (score 5):

`inputenc` redefines the foreign characters to actually be commands that generate the correct glyphs, but this does not work within `\psbarcode`. You must give the `parse` option, and then specify the characters by their three-digit [ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com) code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)
  \psbarcode{^198^216^197^230^248^229}{width=1.0 height=1.0 parse}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```